# How to set an alarm with jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am triyng to set an alarm with Jetpack Compose but does not work i am triyng to test with emulator and with app running on main thread, this is my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    private var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null
    private lateinit var alarmIntent: PendingIntent
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context= LocalContext.current
            navController = rememberNavController()
            NotePadReminderTheme {

                val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                    timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,6)
                    set(Calendar.MINUTE,34)
                }
                val alarmManager =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
                val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                val pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getService(context, 3, intent,0)

                alarmManager?.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,calendar.timeInMillis,pendingIntent)

//                MainPage(navController =navController )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NotePadReminder"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NotePadReminder">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.mobile.notepadreminder.AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my AlarmReceiver class:

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("alarm","received")
    }
}
```

I do not know why does not work.
My problem is that I set the alarm and the alarm does not run never.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which android version are you using to test and which version are you targetting?

Comment: You are using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`, which is time since boot with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, that can't really work. You probably want `AlarmManager.RTC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I needed was to change the getService method to getBroadcast but I don't know why

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        lateinit var navController: NavHostController
        private var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null
        private lateinit var alarmIntent: PendingIntent
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                val context= LocalContext.current
                navController = rememberNavController()
                NotePadReminderTheme {
    
                    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,6)
                        set(Calendar.MINUTE,34)
                    }
                    val alarmManager =
                        context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
                    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    val pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Date().seconds, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    
                    alarmManager?.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,calendar.timeInMillis,pendingIntent)
    
    //                MainPage(navController =navController )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```